# how set a final in a buffer putting a 0?

Tags: c, string, buffer

I'm getting a buffer of internet, I think to go this buffer and find the last character, I have to find the character `'\0'`. But there is no `'\0'` in a buffer.

How set a  final in a buffer putting a 0 to force this buffer to behave like a string?

Comment: What is a buffer of internet? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](//stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

When code is "getting a buffer", certainly either 1a) the `length` of the buffer is known, 1b) or the buffer has a null character at the end and 2) the maximum possible `size` of the buffer is known.

In OP's case, code should know the answer to 1a and 2. then the solution is

```
if (length < size) {
  buffer[length] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate 1 extra byte to hold the buffer you read + the terminating `'\0'`, so if you use `recv()` for example ("*which we don't know because you did not post any code*").

```
char buffer[100];
char *string;
ssize_t recieved;

recieved = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
if (recieved == -1)
    abortThisOperation();
string = malloc(1 + recieved);
if (string == NULL)
    abortThisOperation();
memcpy(string, buffer, recieved);

string[recieved] = '\0';
/* use `string' now ... */
free(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. The problem was solved as well.

```
while ((bytesRcvd = recv (socklio, buf_recev, bufsize - 1, 0))> 0)
```

{
     buf_recev [bytesRcvd] = 0;

Answer (score -1):

If you are allocating the I/O buffer locally, do this:

```
char buff[BUFSIZE + 1];
/* <get-the-data-somehow> */
buff[BUFSIZE] = '\0';
```

Now there is a guaranteed sentinel `'\0'` to find.

Comment: What if the recieved buffer has less than `BUFSIZE` characters?

Comment: I'm assuming that the input operation supplies its own '\0' somewhere in the file and you just need a special case that the buffer is exactly filled and no '\0' was added because there was no room.  Failing that, you'll need to know how long the input was; surely your input method tells you this.

Comment: I don't mean that, I mean suppose the recieved buffer has only `BUFSIZE - 10` bytes, then adding the `'\0'` at the end is not going to make the buffer a string which is probably what the OP wants.

Comment: Adding the final '\0' simply guarantees that functions like strcpy(3) can be safely used on the buffer.  Perhaps the OP can enlighten us.